# How to convert seconds to minutes with decimal point

Tags: sql

I have column that presents number of seconds that took to complete scanning. However I need to translate to minutes and remaining seconds, example if we have 65 seconds I need function to convert to 1.5.
I have used datediff() function to retract minutes from start and end datetime stamp  but it rounds to nearest minutes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is really strange, but you can use strings:

```
select floor(65 / 60) || '.' || (65 % 60)
```

Note:  This uses standard operators but databases may have their own conventions for string concatenation and modulo arithmetic.

Comment: thank you so much, so this is what I ended using based on your function above and it works. convert(varchar(2),ES.email_scan_duration_seconds/60 % 60)+'.'+ 
convert(varchar(2),ES.email_scan_duration_seconds% 60)